# react-router Redirect does not keep localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

In my react SPA I'm implementing a social login, which substantially just works.

The redirect url after the authentication is https://example.com/oauth2, where I am successfully redirected after the social login.

Now I'd like to save my users some *flickering*, so I'd like to redirect oauth2 - say - to `home` route.
Something like:

in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Home from "./Home";
import Oauth2 from "./Oauth2";

export default (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Redirect from="/oauth2" to="/" />
  </Switch>
);
```

The 'issue' I have is that if I redirect using `react-router Redirect`, the user auth info in localstorage is lost, so I lose authentication.

If I do instead:

in App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';
import Home from "./Home";
import Oauth2 from "./Oauth2";

export default (
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
    <Route path="/oauth2" component={Oauth2} />
  </Switch>
);
```

and, in Oauth2.js:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
export default function Oauth2() {
  const history = useHistory();

  useEffect(() => {
    history.replace("/");
  }, [history]);

  return null;
}
```

localstorage is safe, and the redirection works (even though I keep having https://example.com/oauth2 in the address bar, while I'd expect https://example.com/ ...).

I'm afraid I'm using the wrong redirection strategy, or I am not using the *happy path* after social login...

Comment: I dont know about the specific implementation in this oauth lib you are using. But in the oauth2 spec, the auth server will accept a state parameter which it will pass back in the callback uri. This is a link to some google docs https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server its a bit down on the page. You can use this to maintain states such as routes

Comment: Thanks. I just solved asking social OAuth2 setup to redirect directly to `/`, not `/auth2`. I thought this could be in some way less flexible, but it is not... :-)